# jQuery.ajax(..) produces a "Content-CtrlType" header field in POST request

Tags: jquery

I have a realy weird propblem.  Posting JSON data with jQuery.ajax(...) suddenly started to put the content type("application/json" or whatever other content type you might specify) into a request header field named "Content-CtrlType" instead of "Content-Type".  "Content-Type" also exists but contains "text/plain":

[image: Screenshot of weird POST request header]

I use jQuery 1.7.2.  The problem exists on IE9, Firefox 12 and Chrome.  Have not tested other browsers, as I believe it is not browser related.

This is my JavaScript code that generates the request:

```
...
var ajaxOptions = {
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { .... },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { .... },
    converters: {
         "text json": function(data) { .... }
    }
};

$.ajax(ajaxOptions);

...
```

"params" is my JavaScript object holding the data to transmit.

Anyone an idea what goes wrong?

Comment: `ajaxOptions.success =` should just be `success:`, since it's *within* `ajaxOptions` to begin with.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - Sorry, I pasted shortened code.  Did not shorten it correctly.  Just corrected it.  Thanks!

Comment: I replicated the code you have here within a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrKbd/), but am unable to repeat your results. I see only the `content-type` being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after Jonathan confirmed that nothing is wrong with my code I started an in detail debugging session and dived into jQuery code.  And here I found the problem.  Probably as a result of some refactoring the setting of the request header field "Content-Type" was renamed to "Content-CtrlType".  If it would have been renamed to something else it would have been much more obvious.  @*$&§... So much about trifle refactoring...

Sorry for bothering!